# Windows 11 only recognizes one USB-to-Ethernet adapter at the same time, despite two being plugged

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, windows-11

I use Windows 11 on a Dell laptop. It has no built-in Ethernet port, so I use a USB-to-Ethernet adapter. My network works with one adapter, but ultimately I need two at the same time. More specifically, the configuration that I need is the following:

- One USB-to-Ethernet adapter connecting the laptop to the local network, 192.x.x.x
- One USB-to-Ethernet adapter connecting the laptop to a switch, which links several home-made devices to the laptop. *Note: this network will communicate with Ubuntu using WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux). I have tried this configuration with only one USB adapter and WiFi and it works very well, using a Hyper-V Virtual Switch*.

I added a diagram of the needed networks at the end of the post for more clarity.

**Details about the setup:**

- I can use only one adapter on USB-C, because the laptop only has two USB-C connections (one of them is for power input)
- The remaining USB socket is USB 2
- The home-made hardware does not need to communicate with Internet nor the 192.x.x.x network, only with each other and the laptop.

**Details about the problem:**

- In the "Network connections" page (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> --> `ncpa.cpl`), Windows only lists the USB-C Ethernet adapter (the one connected to 192.x.x.x)
- In the peripherals manager, any USB-to-Ethernet adapter that I connect using the USB 2 socket is listed as "other peripherals"
- I tried several USB 2 adapters from different brands. None work, they all display as "USB 2.0 Ethernet Adapter 10/100Mbps". They have no driver"
- I tried to manually install drivers. It moved then to the "network" section of the device manager, but **they appear to be disconnected** even when they are connected.

---

**What I tried so far**:

- I tried this list of commands:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled
netsh int tcp show global
```

They worked when my USB-C adapter had "non-identified network" issues, but not for this case.

- I tried three different USB-to-Ethernet adapters
- I tried installing drivers for the USB-to-Ethernet adapters, as explained above

I am a bit lost.

**What can I do to have two USB-to-Ethernet adapters at the same time, one on USB-C and one on a USB 2 socket?**

---

[image: Desired network connection]

Comment: Since USB-C seems reliable on your PC, have you tried using a hub? Borrow a USB-C to USB-C hub , or one can be bought for US$20 or so. Plug both adapters into the hub.

Comment: That is a good idea, thank you. I will look into it

Comment: Please let us know if it works; you can even explain what you did and answer your own question, if you wish.

Comment: I have no USB-C to USB-C hub yet. I tried a USB-C to USB-A hub, and plugging two USB A-to-Ethernet adapters in the hub. It did not work, none of them were recognized by the PC. Upon further inspecton, it seems that the USB-A adapters that I tried arer not compatible with my computer. I made another question about it here: https://superuser.com/questions/1763396/windows-11-impossible-to-use-usb-2-0-to-ethernet-adapters?noredirect=1#comment2742752_1763396