# Windows 11: impossible to use USB 2.0 to Ethernet adapters

Tags: networking, usb, drivers, ethernet

I need a specific configuration on my Dell laptop with Windows 11 (more details in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1763179/windows-11-only-recognizes-one-usb-to-ethernet-adapter-at-the-same-time-despite?noredirect=1#comment2742405_1763179)). To achieve this configuration, I need the following:

- One USB-to-Ethernet adapter, plugged on the USB type C socket of my laptop
- Another USB-to-Ethernet adapter, plugged to an USB 2.0 socket of my laptop

The USB type C adaptor is detected and works very well as a Realtek Familiy adaptor.

However for some reason, any USB 2.0 (type A) Ethernet adpater that I use refuses to connect. In the **device manager**, they end up in the **Other peripherals** section. They do not have any driver installed.

In the **Network connections** tab (`ncpa.cpl`), only the Wi-Fi adapter shows up (and, if I plugged it in, the USB-C adapter).

---

What I tried:

- I tried different USB 2-to-Ethernet adapters, from different brands. None work.
- I tried to find drivers online for them, to no avail. The ones I have are nameless.
- I tried to install drivers. For instance, I tried the driver called `Realtek USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adapter (Microsoft Corp)`. Once, the device moved to the "Network adapters" tab but displayed as unplugged and hidden. The second time I tried, I had a BSOD and Windows reverted the driver.

This is a screenshot of my device manager and network connections:

[image]

Comment: USB 3 should be able to use USB 2 adapters.  It appears the adapters you are trying to use are not Windows 11 compliant.  I have a Lenovo supplied USB dongle for my laptop that allows me to connect Ethernet. Dell may have such an adapter for your machine.

Comment: What is the exact make and model of this USB to Ethernet adapter? Many of these devices need specific drivers and are simply not universally recognized. This is not just in Windows, but in my experience macOS and Linux as well; specific drivers need to be used.

Comment: @John Good point, I will look into compatible Ethernet adapters with my laptop.

Comment: Have you confirmed the power requires of this non-functional adapter does not exceed the power capabilities of USB 2.0?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Unfortunately, I cannot find a name anywhere for them. Absolutely nothing on the plastic, nor the packaging - I suspect them to be third market, bad quality stuff. The three I have tried have different shapes, but yeah.

Comment: Well, if you can get a MAC address off of them somehow, you can [look that up here](https://macaddress.io) to get a manufacturer name.